# Get 3D coordinates of vertices of rotated and scaled cuboid with scale, center position and rotation on all axis

Tags: java, math, geometry, lwjgl, trigonometry

I have been wrecking my brain trying to figure out this problem I have.
I have a cuboid, its rotation on all 3 axis in relation to the world from its center (it's on 3D space), the cuboid's center's position and the scale of the cube in all axis (width, height and depth). I need to find the coordinates of all of the vertices of the cuboid.
While browsing the internet, I only found examples for the 2D cases, and couldn't figure out how to advance to 3D space.
 
 
Can anyone help me please? I will use it in a game engine made with LWJGL (Light Weight Java Game Library).

**Edit: (for @httpdigest):**

```
public Vector3f[] getExtents(){

    Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f();

    m.translate(getPosition());
    m.rotate(getRotation().x, new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
    m.rotate(getRotation().y, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0));
    m.rotate(getRotation().z, new Vector3f(0, 0, 1));
    m.scale(new Vector3f(getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getScaleZ()));
    Vector3f[] corners = new Vector3f[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++) {
        int x = i % 2 * 2 - 1;
        int y = i / 2 % 2 * 2 - 1;
        int z = i / 4 % 2 * 2 - 1;
        Vector4f corner = Matrix4f.transform(m, new Vector4f(x, y, z, 1), null);
        corners[i] = new Vector3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    }
    return corners;
}
```

This still isn't accurate, can anyone spot the problem?

**Edit: Solution:**
The angles needed to be in radians, thanks for the support!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not quite clear, since there are multiple ways to define "its rotation on all 3 axis in relation to the world from its center." Please define that more precisely. But more important, explain how this is a problem in practical computer programming (the purpose of this site) rather than in mathematics, as it now appears.

Comment: What language do you want to use? As it is written now, I'm not sure how this question relates to programming.

Comment: Java, LWJGL is what I'm using @JanBoyer

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I've updated the question. I'm not quite sure on the name of this type of rotation, but I just need a conversion from 2d to 3d (I have an example of the 2d answer in [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490115/how-to-find-corners-of-square-from-its-center-point)

Comment: I'm not looking for a *name* for the rotation, but a *definition* as given in your code. One way to define a 3D rotation is with a 3x3 orthonormal matrix with determinant `1`. Another way is to give a rotation angle counterclockwise around an axis parallel to the x-axis, then another parallel to the y-axis, then another parallel to the z-axis. And there are others. How does your code define the rotation? You may need to show a code sample. Also, your 2D link is pretty worthless since no rotation is involved.

Comment: I have a 3 dimensional vector containing (as you said in your second example) a rotation angle counterclockwise around an axis for each axis. @RoryDaulton

Comment: How does a 3D vector contain a rotation angle, much less one for each axis? If you mean you have three rotation angles, in what order are they applied? (The order matters--note the `then`s I used in my last comment.) It seems we are unable to understand each other unless you show code.

Comment: @RoryDaulton a vector is just the way I store the information, I have only one rotation angle per axis, therfore I have 3 rotation angles and I find it convenient to store it in a 3D vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using LWJGL you can also use JOML, in which case the following is *probably* what you *might* want:

```java
import org.joml.*;
public class CubePositions {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Cuboid center position */
    float px = 10, py = 0, pz = 0;
    /* Euler angles around x, y and z */
    float ax = 0, ay = 0, az = (float) java.lang.Math.PI / 2.0f;
    /* Scale factor for x, y und z */
    float sx = 1, sy = 3, sz = 1;
    /* Build transformation matrix */
    Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f()
        .translate(px, py, pz) // <- translate to position
        .rotateXYZ(ax, ay, az) // <- rotation about x, then y, then z
        .scale(sx, sy, sz);    // <- scale
    /* Compute cube corners and print them */
    Vector3f[] corners = new Vector3f[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < corners.length; i++) {
      int x = i % 2 * 2 - 1;
      int y = i / 2 % 2 * 2 - 1;
      int z = i / 4 % 2 * 2 - 1;
      corners[i] = m.transformPosition(x, y, z, new Vector3f());
      System.out.println(String.format(
          "Corner (%+d, %+d, %+d) = %s",
          x, y, z, corners[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

It computes a transformation matrix `M = T * Rx * Ry * Rz * S` given the center position, Euler rotations around x, then y and then z and the given scaling factors of the unit axes, and then transforms the positions of the unit cube corners by that matrix via `P' = M * P`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! it is certainly better than what I had before, take a look of how I converted it to LWJGL and maybe you can spot the problem, because it seems like there is only 1 axis wrong (I'm placing my bet on the Z axis since its starting value in your code is different). Thanks for the support! also would appreciate if you'd explain why does the rotation on the Z axis is   java.lang.Math.PI / 2.0f at the start

Comment: Yes @httpdigest, I did and it indeed worked! Thank you and have a wonderful week!