# How to transform QMatrix4x4 with scaling, position and angles to find out the vertices of cuboid?

Tags: c++, qt, matrix-multiplication

I have the position of the centre, scaling values(l,w,h) and the orientation angle is degrees ?
I want to rotate the matrix using these values. I have the following code to transform the matrix.
I have a doubt on the angles part. How to pass these values to the matrix. As of now I've passed those as Quartenion, but was not sure about it. These values are in degrees.

```
QMatrix4x4 matrix;
qInfo () << matrix;

float Cuboid_centre_x = -26.6619, Cuboid_centre_y = -36.2277 , Cuboid_centre_z = -0.26431;

// Angles around x,y,z
float ax = 0, ay = 0, az = 0;

// Scale factor for x, y and z (length, width, height)
float sx =  3.79948, sy = 1.44547, sz = 1.05955;

//Translate position
matrix.translate(Cuboid_centre_x, Cuboid_centre_y, Cuboid_centre_z);
qInfo () << matrix;

// Rotate by angles
QQuaternion q = Qt3DCore::QTransform::fromEulerAngles(ax,ay,az);
matrix.rotate(q);
qInfo () << matrix;

// Scale by dimensions
matrix.scale(sx, sy, sz);
qInfo () << matrix;

QVector3D corners[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int x = i % 2 * 2 - 1;
    int y = i / 2 % 2 * 2 - 1;
    int z = i / 4 % 2 * 2 - 1;
    corners[i] = matrix.map(QVector3D(x,y,z));
    qInfo () << corners[i];
}
```

Please suggest. The values I printed from these don not match my output.

I am expecting the values to be around

QVector3D(-28.561613082885743, -36.95038986206055, -0.26546499133110049)
QVector3D(-24.76213264465332, -36.95038986206055, -0.26546499133110049)
QVector3D(-28.561613082885743, -36.95038986206055, 0.7940845489501953)

QVector3D( -24.76213264465332, -36.95038986206055, 0.7940845489501953)
QVector3D(-28.561613082885743, -35.50492477416992, -0.26546499133110049)
QVector3D(-24.76213264465332, -35.50492477416992, -0.26546499133110049)
QVector3D(-28.561613082885743, -35.50492477416992, 0.7940845489501953)
QVector3D(-24.76213264465332, -35.50492477416992, -0.26546499133110049)

Comment: is the order correct? Depending on what you try to achieve: first rotate, then translate

Comment: I am not sure about the order. I had taken a reference from a link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483021/get-3d-coordinates-of-vertices-of-rotated-and-scaled-cuboid-with-scale-center-p

Comment: It is solved. We need scale more i.e giving the scale ratio.

 matrix.scale(0.5);